# Power Apps, SortByColumns, matching Dropdown choice to Column Name

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

When I try my formula in browsegallery, I am only seeing data for the drop down CAATT ID and Requestor. I cant find out why my other dropdown choices arent working here.

Could it be column type? or could it be the column names are wrong? I am getting my column names from MS List.

```
If(
    Toggle2.Value = false,
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            Or(Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email), Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email)) && TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "Doc_Type", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATT ID", "Title", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Status", "Approval Status", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Automation Type", "Automation Type", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approver", "Approver", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approval Date", "Approval Date",Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATTS Name", "CAATTs Name", "ID"),
        Ascending
    ),
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(
            [@'Documentation Tracker'],
            TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ),
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "Doc_Type", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATT ID", "Title", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Status", "Approval Status", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Automation Type", "Automation Type", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approver", "Approver", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approval Date", "Approval Date",Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATTS Name", "CAATTs Name", "ID"),
        Ascending
    )
)
```

Update new code:

```
If(
    Toggle2.Value = false,
    SortByColumns( AddColumns([@'Documentation Tracker'], "Doc_TypeValue", Doc_Type.Value),
        Filter(
            [@'ICFR Documentation Tracker'],
            Or(Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email), Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email)) && TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ), 
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "Doc_TypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATT ID", "Title", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Status", "RequirementsApproval.Selected", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Automation Type", "DocumentationType", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approver", "Approver", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approval Date", "RequirementsApprovalDate",Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATTS Name", "CAATTsName", "ID"),
        Ascending
    ),
    SortByColumns( AddColumns([@'Documentation Tracker'], "Doc_TypeValue", Doc_Type.Value),
        Filter(
            [@'ICFR Documentation Tracker'],
            TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
        ), 
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "Doc_TypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATT ID", "Title", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Status", "RequirementsApproval.Selected", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Automation Type", "DocumentationType", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approver", "Approver", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approval Date", "RequirementsApprovalDate",Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATTS Name", "CAATTsName", "ID"),
        Ascending
    )
)
```

Ive added the line `AddColumns([@'Documentation Tracker'],, "Doc_TypeValue", Doc_Type.Value)` after my `SortByColumn`, still getting an error.

`Doc_Type` is my field name in my sharepoint list

Does this make sense ?

Comment: What is the data type of all these columns which you are using for sorting?

Comment: By Type do you mean like "Single line of Text" vs "Choice" etc?  I have a mix of both of these along with Date and Time

Comment: @GaneshSanap any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this problem because of data type of your list columns. SortByColumns function will work fine with "Single line of text", "Number" or "Date and Time" columns simply by referring column names in formula.

But, sort on complex fields like "Choice" or "Person or Group" column will not work this way.

You have to get the value/property from these complex field based on which you will sort your gallery.

**Example**:

**SharePoint list data**:

[image]

To filter gallery based on Choice (Status) column, Person or Group (PersonCol) I have used formula like this:

```
SortByColumns(
    AddColumns(ReCreate, "StatusValue", Status.Value, "PersonColValue", PersonCol.DisplayName),
    If(
        Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Title",
        "Title",
        Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Modified",
        "Modified",
        Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Status",
        "StatusValue",
        Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Person Column",
        "PersonColValue",
        "ID"
    ),
    Ascending
)
```

Here I am filtering gallery items based on display name of Person or Group column.

**Output**:

[image]

---

Similarly, you have to adjust your formula based on data types you are using.

**Documentations**:

1. [AddColumns, DropColumns, RenameColumns, and ShowColumns functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-table-shaping)
2. [Sort and SortByColumns functions in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-sort)

---

**Update from comments**:

Try using below formula for your requirements:

```
If(
    Toggle2.Value = false,
    SortByColumns(
        AddColumns(
            Filter(
                [@'ICFR Documentation Tracker'],
                Or(Lower(Requestor_two) = Lower(User().Email), Lower(Approver.Value) = Lower(User().Email)) && TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
            ),
            "Doc_TypeValue", Doc_Type.Value
        ), 
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "Doc_TypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATT ID", "Title", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Status", "RequirementsApproval.Selected", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Automation Type", "DocumentationType", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approver", "Approver", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approval Date", "RequirementsApprovalDate",Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATTS Name", "CAATTsName", "ID"),
        Ascending
    ),
    SortByColumns(
        AddColumns(
            Filter(
                [@'ICFR Documentation Tracker'],
                TextSearchBox1.Text in Title
            ),
            "Doc_TypeValue", Doc_Type.Value
        ),
        If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "Doc_TypeValue", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Requestor", "Requestor_two", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATT ID", "Title", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Status", "RequirementsApproval.Selected", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Automation Type", "DocumentationType", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approver", "Approver", Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Approval Date", "RequirementsApprovalDate",Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "CAATTS Name", "CAATTsName", "ID"),
        Ascending
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, it is coming together now. Still getting an error though :(

Comment: For which column & data type are you getting an error? can you show the formula you are using now?

Comment: I've updated the question to include my new formula. DocType is a choice column

Comment: For `AddColumns` function, you don't need to use internal names (you can use column names using power apps suggestions/IntelliSense). Also, replace `ReCreate` with name of your list. What is the error message while using this formula? Refer [this thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Sorting-Choice-Column-with-SortByColumns/td-p/1199813) while writing formula.

Comment: Thanks. So I am doing this: `SortByColumns( AddColumns([@'Documentation Tracker'], "Doc_TypeValue", Doc_Type.Value)`    Doc_Type is my column header. 
And my dropdown is like this  `If(Dropdown1.Selected.Value = "Documentation Type", "DocTypeValue"` Not sure what to do here.

Comment: SortByColumns has some invalid arguments is the error msg

Comment: Check updated answer for new formula.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh! it works! btw when I implement this.. my app Item = VarRecord on EditForm1 now has an error. but when I remove `AddColumns` from your new answer, Item = VaRRecord works fine.

Comment: You can use DropColumns function to remove newly added columns. Check reference link given in above comments.

Comment: hey Ganesh, wher would I use this DropColumns function?

Comment: DropColumns will be outer most function in formula. Check example formula at: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Sorting-Choice-Column-with-SortByColumns/m-p/1199959/highlight/true#M314602